# Iterating a changing container

Tags: c++, dynamic, iteration

I am iterating over a set of callback functions. Functions are called during iteration and may lead to drastic changes to the actual container of the functions set.

What I am doing now is:

1. make a copy of original set
2. iterate over copy, but for every element check whether it still exists in the original set

Checking for every element's existence is super-dynamic, but seems quite slow too.

Are there other propositions to tackle this case?

Edit : here is the actual code :

```
    // => i = event id
    template <class Param>
    void dispatchEvent(int i, Param param) {

        EventReceiverSet processingNow;

        const EventReceiverSet& eventReceiverSet = eventReceiverSets[i];
        std::copy(eventReceiverSet.begin(), eventReceiverSet.end(), std::inserter(processingNow, processingNow.begin()));

        while (!processingNow.empty()) {
            EventReceiverSet::iterator it = processingNow.begin();
            IFunction<>* function = it->getIFunction(); /// get function before removing iterator
            processingNow.erase(it);

            // is EventReceiver still valid? (may have been removed from original set)
            if (eventReceiverSet.find(ERWrapper(function)) == eventReceiverSet.end()) continue; // not found

            function->call(param);
        }
    };
```

Comment: By "set" do you mean `std::set<>`? If not, what is the actual container type?

Comment: Well, I wanted to leave this generic, but yes, it is an std::set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two basic approaches come to mind:

1. use a task based approach (with the collection locked, push tasks onto a queue for each element, then release all parties to do work and wait till completion). You'll still need a check to see whether the element for the current task is still present/current in the collection when the task is actually starting.

   - this could leverage reader-writer locks for the checks, which is usually speedier than fullblown mutual exclusions (especially with more readers than writers)
2. use a concurrent data structure (I mean, one that is suitable for multithreaded access without explicit locking). The following libraries contain implementations of concurrent data structures:

   - [Intel Thread Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/)
   - [MS ConCrt concurrent_vector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355343.aspx)
   - [libcds Concurrent Data Structures](http://libcds.sourceforge.net/)

(adding links shortly)

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do it in two steps: first, go through the original set, and make a set of action items. Then go through the set of action items, and apply them to the original set.

An action item is a base class with subclasses. Each subclass takes in a set, and performs a specific operation on it, for example:

```
struct set_action {
    virtual void act(std::set<int> mySet) const;
};
class del_action : public set_action {
private:
    int item;
public:
    del_action(int _item) : item(_item) {}
    virtual void act(std::set<int> mySet) const {
        // delete item from set
    }
};
class upd_action : public set_action {
private:
    int from, to;
public:
    upd_action(int _from, int _to) : from(_from), to(_to) {}
    virtual void act(std::set<int> mySet) const {
        // delete [from], insert [to]
    }
};
```

Now you can create a collection of `set_action*`s in the first pass, and run them in the second pass.

Answer (score 3):

The operations which mutate the `set` structure are `insert()` and `erase()`.

While iterating, consider **using the iterator returned by the mutating operations**.

```
it = myset.erase( it );
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/erase/

Comment: The link you cited says :

void set::erase ( iterator position );